# dm all command discord js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

i want the command to dm 1 member then wait 5 seconds then dm the next member untill all members are dm by the bot

this is the code i have

```js
if (command === 'dmall') {
  message.guild.members.cache.forEach(async (member) => {
    const messageSent = await member.send(args[0]);
    console.log(messageSent);
    await wait(5000);
  });
}
```

the error i get is member.send is not function

this is the wait thing it has no problems

```js
let wait = (ms) => {
  if (!ms) throw new TypeError("Time isn't specified");
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
};
```

Comment: Have you add `GUILD_MEMBERS` intent to your client?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working for me. So the problem is not in your code that you give probably.

You must add [`GUILD_MEMBERS`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) intent to your client in order to read all the guild member user data.

You should replace your code with this when creating a new [client](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client) instances :

```
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS] });
```

( Or if you have another intents, just add `Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS` to it. )

> Note : This intent is privilaged. Which means if you add this intents to your bot, [it will not be able to join any guild anymore after 100 guild reached until your bot verified](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/360040720412-Bot-Verification-and-Data-Whitelisting). If this is a private bot. Then it would be fine.

Also make sure to catch an error in your code when you send a message to all member to prevent your bot to crashing when :

- A user disabling 'Allow direct message from server member'
- A user is a bot. It's impossible to DM a bot.

So it should be :

```
if (command === 'dmall') {
  message.guild.members.cache.forEach(async (member) => {
    const messageSent = await member.send(args[0])
    .catch(err => {console.log(err)});
    console.log(messageSent);
    await wait(5000);
  });
}
```

Tell me if its works or not.